# Cannot get the correct utf-8 text from Access

Tags: php, ms-access, encoding, utf-8

When I tried to get chinese characters from the database, I got weird text.
I tried almost everything, like `html_entity_decode`, `htmlentities`, save the file using utf-8, encode in utf-8, but I can't seem to get it right.

How do i get the right text?

Here's my code:

```php
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' /> 
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$conn=odbc_connect('vocab','',''); 
$rs1=odbc_exec($conn,"SELECT MAX(ID) AS MaxId FROM vocab");
$NewMaxID=odbc_result($rs1,"MaxId");
$rand=rand(1,$NewMaxID);


            $sql="SELECT word,part_of_speech,chinese FROM vocab WHERE ID=".$rand.";";
            $rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);


            $i=1;
            odbc_fetch_row($rs);
$a=(odbc_result($rs,1));
$b=(odbc_result($rs,2));    
$c=(odbc_result($rs,3));


//$c="&#37806;";
//$d=html_entity_decode($c);
//$c=htmlentities($d, ENT_NOQUOTES , "UTF-8");
$rows=array("first"=>$a,"second"=>$b,"third"=>$c);
echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

ps: I am using Traditional Chinese version of MS Office.

Comment: can you try mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
$result2 = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); before your query

Comment: $sql="SET CHARACTER SET utf8";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
$sql="SET NAMES utf8";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue a while ago and the only way I could get it to work was to write the HTML into an `ADODB.Stream` object, save it to a file, and then `echo` the file:

```php
<?php
define("TEMP_FOLDER", "C:\\__tmp\\");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$stm = new COM("ADODB.Stream") or die("Cannot create COM object.");
$stm->Type = 2;  // adTypeText
$stm->Charset = 'utf-8';
$stm->Open();
$stm->WriteText('<html>');
$stm->WriteText('<head>');
$stm->WriteText('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />');
$stm->WriteText('<title>ADODB test</title>');
$stm->WriteText('</head>');
$stm->WriteText('<body>');

$con = new COM("ADODB.Connection"); 
$con->Open(
        "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" .
        "Dbq=C:\\Users\\Public\\Database1.accdb");
$rst = $con->Execute("SELECT word FROM vocab WHERE ID=3");
$stm->WriteText($rst->Fields("word"));
$rst->Close();
$con->Close();

$stm->WriteText('</body>');
$stm->WriteText('</html>');

$tempFile = TEMP_FOLDER . uniqid("", TRUE) . ".txt";
$stm->SaveToFile($tempFile, 2);  // adSaveCreateOverWrite
$stm->Close();
echo file_get_contents($tempFile);
unlink($tempFile);
?>
```

Comment: Solved by changing the language used by MS Office to Tradtional Chinese(Tai Wan).