# Is there any way to change MS ACCESS character encoding?

Tags: ms-access, character-encoding

First I have issues when I post UTF-8 characters on MS ACCESS (mdb) database via PHP.

After I'm converting enconding to ISO-8859-1 to show characters correctly from database.

But I didn't like this solution.

If I can change Access Encoding my problem is solved. If not, I still stay with my bad solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert MS Access database encoding to UTF-8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222705/how-to-convert-ms-access-database-encoding-to-utf-8)

Comment: @Bartdude, In that question nobody says if is possible to change MS ACCESS database

Comment: Well the second answer may well help you. it would also help to know which version of access we're talking about. Probably < 2007 as the default encoding from there is UTF-8 AFAIK

Comment: @Bartude, I'm already converting character encoding into php. What I want is to know if is possible to convert my database file permanently.

Comment: I had a similar problem a while back and the only way I could get it to work was to use ADO as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19906108/2144390). (I couldn't get either PDO-ODBC or legacy PHP ODBC support to work with UTF-8 characters in Access.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for attention and suggestions. I think there is no way to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

In vb

```
x = StrConv(MyText, vbFromUnicode)
```

Or
In sql

```
StrConv(MyText, 64)
```

But befor send your data with php you can convert charset of text by using iconv function or other php functions.