# PHP ODBC Cannot print Chinese for MS Access, but COM can

Tags: php, codeigniter, ms-access, utf-8, odbc

I am trying to print Chinese using the ODBC that is connected to MS Access. It does not work for ODBC driver but works for ADODB, I need to use ODBC because of codeigniter existing library. Any solution for this ? Thanks

```
        ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');              
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        echo '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />'; 

        $conn=odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};CharSet=utf8;DBQ=//192.168.8.130/MainC/POS_AY.mdb",'','');
        $sql  = "SELECT Size FROM MenuSetPrice";
        $rs= odbc_exec($conn,$sql);          
        odbc_fetch_row($rs) ;
        $Size=odbc_result($rs,"Size");

        echo $Size; // THIS NOT WORKING, it print on the browser ?
         echo mb_detect_encoding($Size); // This return ASCII

        $db_connection = new COM("ADODB.Connection", NULL, CP_UTF8);
        $db_connstr = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=//192.168.8.130/MainC/POS_AY.mdb";

        $db_connection->open($db_connstr);
        $rs = $db_connection->execute("SELECT Size  FROM MenuSetPrice");
        $rs_fld0 = $rs->Fields(0);

        echo ($rs_fld0->value); // THIS WORKS, it print 例
        echo mb_detect_encoding($rs_fld0->value); // THIS RETURN UTF-8

        $rs->Close();
        $db_connection->Close();
```

UPDATE : 
Added the mb_detect_encoding code. How come the ODBC returning ASCII ? Is there a way to connect ODBC to return UTF-8 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot get the correct utf-8 text from Access](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19892026/2144390).