# Use of undefined constant ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC - assumed 'ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC'

Tags: php, adodb

why does the ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC undefined. What extension I must enable ?

```
        $db_connection = new COM("ADODB.Connection", NULL, CP_UTF8);
        $db_connstr = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=//192.168.8.130/MainC/POS_AY.mdb";
        $db_connection->SetFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC); 
        $db_connection->open($db_connstr);
        $rs = $db_connection->execute("SELECT Description FROM Menu");
```

Comment: Looks like you're mixing up methods for the *freaking prehistoric* "[ADOdb for PHP](http://phplens.com/adodb/)" library and the ADO API provided in Windows.  They are not the same thing and you can't freely interchange their syntax.  If you need to connect to an Access database from PHP, you should probably be using ODBC (say, [through PDO](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.connection.php))

Comment: I see. Thanks
I did use the ODBC first, but it can't print Chinese character properly. This is my posted problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853057/php-odbc-cannot-print-chinese-for-ms-access-but-com-can